# Project 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:3.0.2' not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am new to api development. I imported this project from my friend but now I am getting these error.:-

```
     Project 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:3.0.2' not found
        Project 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:3.0.2' not found
        Project 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:3.0.2' not found
        Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":properties}'. One of '{"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":packaging, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":url, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":inceptionYear, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":organization, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":licenses, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":developers, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":contributors, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":mailingLists, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":prerequisites, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":modules, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":scm, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":issueManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":ciManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":distributionManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":dependencyManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":dependencies, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":repositories, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":pluginRepositories, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":build, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":reports, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":reporting, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":profiles}' is expected.
 Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":properties}'. One of '{"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":packaging, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":url, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":inceptionYear, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":organization, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":licenses, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":developers, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":contributors, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":mailingLists, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":prerequisites, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":modules, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":scm, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":issueManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":ciManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":distributionManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":dependencyManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":dependencies, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":repositories, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":pluginRepositories, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":build, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":reports, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":reporting, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":profiles}' is expected.
     Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:' not found
     Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:' not found
     Dependency 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:' not found
     Dependency 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:' not found
     Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:' not found
     Dependency 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:' not found
     Dependency 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:' not found
     Dependency 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:8.0.1' not found
     Dependency 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:8.0.1' not found
     Dependency 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:8.0.1' not found
     Plugin 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:' not found
     Plugin 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:' not found
```

Here is my pom.xml file :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.square</groupId>
    <artifactId>square</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>square</name>
    <description>square</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried to invalidate and restart cache. I don't know how to solve this problem. I am trying to solve this problem from yesterday but I am getting any solution to solve this problem. Someone please help me I am stucked here.

Comment: Using java 7 ... will not work. Spring 3.X requires JDK17+... also your error output looks like you have configured something strange ... which Maven version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I noticed that you have a duplicate `<properties> </properties>`

I wasn't able to replicate your issue, Spring Boot 3 needs at least Java 17 to run, which is a requirement I do not currently have.

However, I migrated to version `2.6.4` which is compatible with Java version 11 and I noticed that you had the version of `mysql-connector-j` missing

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.31</version> // add version
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Remove

```
 <properties>
   <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
 </properties>
```

Find below the full `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.square</groupId>
    <artifactId>square</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>square</name>
    <description>square</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.31</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If you still want to use the same Spring Boot version that you currently have, make sure you have Java 17, and delete `.m2` file if you think it might be a cache issue, and do the same changes regarding the `properties` tag and `mysql` version.

Hope this helps!